# Borrar un usuario logueado a traves de su panel de control con php y mysql a través de un modal bootstrap

Tags: php

Hola estoy intentando borrar desde el panel de control al usuario que está logueado. Lo estoy haciendo a través de PHP con MySQL y en vez de que el botón eliminar me lleve a otra página distinta, le he puesto un modal y lo haga en la misma. En caso correcto, me ponga un mensaje en otra página de que el usuario se ha eliminado correctamente y un enlace para regresar al index.php y en caso de que falle, también el botón para que vuelva al index.php para que vuelva a loguearse y lo intente de nuevo. Pero el problema es que cuando me logueo con el usuario que he registrado y doy en el botón eliminar y se me abre el modal y clico en eliminar no hace nada, no llama al php encargado para eliminar al usuario y no encuentro el fallo si es que lo hay o si estoy llamando mal al archivo.

Código panel de control donde se encuentra el botón y modal eliminar:

```
<?php
session_start();

    // $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];

    // $sql = "SELECT usuario FROM web_users WHERE '$usuario'";

    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {

    } else {
        header('Location: ../index.php');//redirige a la página de login si el usuario quiere ingresar sin iniciar sesion


    exit;
    }

    $now = time();

    if($now > $_SESSION['expire']) {
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: #Login');//redirige a la página de login, modifica la url a tu conveniencia
        echo "Tu sesion a expirado,
        <a href='#Login'>Inicia Sesion</a>";
        exit;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Perfil</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
            $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
            $('.debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' + $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href') + '</strong>');
        });
    </script>
    <!-- Eliminando el subrayado de los links -->
    <style type="text/css">
        a:link
        {
        text-decoration:none;
        }
        #delete {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #FF0000;
            border-color: #FF0000;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 6px 12px;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.42857143;
            text-align: center;
            white-space: nowrap;
            vertical-align: middle;
            touch-action: manipulation;
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            background-image: none;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        #delete:hover {
            background-color: #CC0000;
        }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
          <h1>Bienvenido <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario'];?></h1>
          <p>Manten tu perfil actualizado</p>
          <a href="logout.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success"> Cerrar Sesión</button></a>
          <a href="#" data-href="eliminar-usuario.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><button id="delete">Eliminar Usuario</button></a>
        </div>
        <!-- <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>        Esta línea crea un icono papelera -->
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <a href="../index.php"><h3>Inicio</h3></a>
              <p>Volver a la página de Inicio</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <a href=""><h3>EHCP</h3></a>
              <p>Entrar al Panel de control</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <a href="../edit_profile.php"><h3>Editar Perfil</h3></a>
              <p>Edita tus datos personales</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Eliminar Usuario</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ¿Desea eliminar el usuario? Se le borrará todos los datos de forma irreversible.
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Eliminar</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Código eliminar usuario:

```
<?php

    require('conexion.php');

    // Mantiene la sesión iniciada
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }
    var_dump($_SESSION);

    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM web_users WHERE id = '$id'";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

?>

<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                <?php if($resultado) { ?>
                <h3>USUARIO ELIMINADO</h3>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <h3>ERROR AL ELIMINAR EL USUARIO</h3>
                <?php } ?>
                <a href="../index.php" class="btn btn-primary">Regresar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No sería más sencillo meter los botones del modal en un formulario, y enviarlo por post a la página de borrado, en lugar de usar una sesión?

Comment: He probado en vez de pasar el id con la sesión, haciendo el post con el usuario que está logueado y tampoco me hace nada:

`$usuario = $_POST['usuario']`

y despues en la consulta le he pasado el usuario en vez del id pero no me funciona tampoco

Comment: Primeramente, no necesitas un modal para esto, puedes usar Ajax e intentar la eliminación desde la misma página sin necesidad de recargar, es más simple y mejor desde el punto de vista de la UX (le ahorraras al usuario tener que estarse moviendo entre un modal y la página principal). Dicho eso, te recomiendo que depures tu código, usando la consola en cuanto a JavaScript y var_dump para PHP. Verifica que en cada punto se están recogiendo y enviando los datos correctos, que las consultas funcionan, etc. y nos dices entonces en qué lugar falla exactamente. Por último usa el punto y aparte.

Comment: el modal es, por si el usuario quiere borrar su perfil, que le salga una ventana emergente diciendo esta seguro que quiere borrar todos sus datos?, por eso. Nunca he usado Ajax y por tema de tiempo ando justo ya que es un proyecto para el CFGS ASIR y tengo hasta la semana del 24 de este para terminar. Y me queda solamente eso y dos cosillas más.
Sin el data-href, me funciona y borra el usuario de forma correcta pero con el data-href es que no hace nada, ni error en consola ni en red en el navegador